# read file csv and do the aggregation with multiple workers , dask.distributed , dask.dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, dask, dask-distributed, dask-dataframe

i have server ip:192.168.33.10 launche the schudeler `dask scheduler --host 0.0.0.0` this is master in this server i have file "/var/shared/job_skills.csv" and the workers is
192.168.33.11,192.168.33.12 launched with this cmd `dask worker 192.168.33.10:8786  --local-directory /var/test --dashboard-address 8787 --host 0.0.0.0 --worker-port 39040 --nanny-port 39042`
i wanna start script read_csv.py in master and distribute the task to worker , like chunck the data and do aggregation and every worker return result and print result .

i wannna do like this
this scripte in master "read_csv.py"

```
import dask
import dask.dataframe as dd
from dask.distributed import Client

dask.config.set({"dataframe.convert-string": False})

client = Client("192.168.33.10:8786")
df = dd.read_csv("/var/shared/foo.csv")

df['job_skills'] = df['job_skills'].fillna('')
df = df["job_skills"].str.split(',').explode().str.strip()

grouped = df.value_counts().compute()
print(grouped)
```

in the workers give me like this :

```
2024-02-29 14:30:04,180 - distributed.worker - WARNING - Compute Failed
Key:       ('str-strip-956897fad2adeffa85aa604734f0febb', 0)
Function:  execute_task
args:      ((subgraph_callable-50304a7f18bfe19fd3ff56b4a6d6db4f, 'str', 'strip', (), {}, 'explode-e2622e44a85e1396024ff799e4f97b6e', 'split', {'pat': ',', 'n': -1, 'expand': False}, 'getitem-f2b8974c7433cce59ce3453d7f35940e', 'job_skills', '', 'getitem-b9a23a03a236420b7c31ada8ec6055df', [(<function read_block_from_file at 0x7fd18829f920>, <OpenFile '/var/shared/foo.csv'>, 0, 1398, b'\n'), None, True, True]))
kwargs:    {}
Exception: "FileNotFoundError(2, 'No such file or directory')"
```

how i can resolve this ?

Comment: To be sure: can the client see that path, can the workers? If they are on different machines, I suppose they have completely unconnected filesystems.

Comment: how i can check if the workers can see the path

Comment: This is something you should know, since you have control of those machines. Does the file exist at that path on the machines the worker is running on?

Comment: i don't wanna copie the file to workers because is so big i want master chunck the file and give the workers part

Comment: I recommend SSH. What you want cannot be done automatically.

Comment: i don't understand what do you mean

Comment: What you want cannot be achieved. You will need to make the file available to all workers (and client) via ssh, and use a URL like ssh://... .

Comment: yeah i want do like this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to solve this without copying the file to workers.

- make sure that the machine hosting the file has sshd running (i.e., you can ssh to it from the worker machines)
- that ssh access from the client and workers is via keys and not username/password (you need any connection to be non-interactive)
- make your read command something like

```
df = dd.read_csv("ssh://server:port//var/shared/foo.csv")
```

Now each workers will read directly from source, and only those bytes it will be working on.

Possible alternatives for others:

- mount a shared filesystem like NFS, so that the file appears like a local file the workers and client
- store the file in object store instead of a normal disk location. This object store could still be local, such as minio which provides an S3-compatible API.